# "error: not 32-bit: 2" when using cython complied code on kivy based android app

Tags: android, cython, kivy

I used cython to try improve a bottleneck in my code on a kivy application I have designed for android, everything works fine when I try to run it on my computer but I get:

"ImportError: dlopen failed: "/storage/emulated/0/org.test.Bos/offset_lay_mod.so" not 32-bit: 2"  in the logcat when I try to launch it on android.

I am using 64bit Ubuntu so I know that may be an issue but I don't know enough to be able to rectify the issue, do I have to recompile the offset_lay_mod.so using 32-bit compiler or am I wrong trying to run cython on an app for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your code for arm you can't use x86 compiled code on arm android.
Just write a [py4a recipe](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/recipe.sh.tmpl) for your code.

Comment: Thanks, that should keep me occupied for a few hours!